# Problems viewing flurry data with android

Tags: android, events, boolean, logging, flurry

I am using Flurry for analytics in my android app, and for one event I want to record a boolean. I am using the following code:

```
FlurryAgent.logEvent(event, b);
```

This logs the event on Flurry.com but when I click into the event I can only see how many times it has been logged, not how many times true or false were logged.

To clarify, on Flurry.com I can't see any difference between logging and event, and logging an event with a boolean.

Does anyone know if there is anything I am missing or if it just doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is on the flurry bug-fixing roadmap.